# I am using Twilio in python but I get ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, twilio

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.sip.domain.auth_types.auth_type_registrations.auth_registrations_credential_list_mapping'`

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client


# Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
# and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
account_sid = "MY_ACCOUNT_SID"
auth_token = "MY_AUTH_TOKEN"
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages \
                .create(
                     body="Join Earth's mightiest heroes. Like Kevin Bacon.",
                     from_='NUMBER',
                     to='NUMBER'
                 )

print(message.sid)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\code\python\100-days-of-code\Section 35\rain_alert\sample.py", line 12, in <module>
    message = client.messages \
  File "C:\Users\smitk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\twilio\rest\__init__.py", line 676, in messages
    return self.api.account.messages
  File "C:\Users\smitk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\twilio\rest\__init__.py", line 183, in api
    from twilio.rest.api import Api
  File "C:\Users\smitk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\twilio\rest\api\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from twilio.rest.api.ApiBase import ApiBase
  File "C:\Users\smitk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\twilio\rest\api\ApiBase.py", line 16, in <module>
    from twilio.rest.api.v2010 import V2010
  File "C:\Users\smitk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\twilio\rest\api\v2010\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from twilio.rest.api.v2010.account import AccountList
  File "C:\Users\smitk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\twilio\rest\api\v2010\account\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.sip import SipList
  File "C:\Users\smitk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\twilio\rest\api\v2010\account\sip\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.sip.domain import DomainList
  File "C:\Users\smitk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\twilio\rest\api\v2010\account\sip\domain\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.sip.domain.auth_types import AuthTypesList
  File "C:\Users\smitk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\twilio\rest\api\v2010\account\sip\domain\auth_types\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.sip.domain.auth_types.auth_type_registrations import (
  File "C:\Users\smitk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\twilio\rest\api\v2010\account\sip\domain\auth_types\auth_type_registrations\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.sip.domain.auth_types.auth_type_registrations.auth_registrations_credential_list_mapping import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.sip.domain.auth_types.auth_type_registrations.auth_registrations_credential_list_mapping'
```

I think problem in twilio package. So I reinstall package but every time I get same error.

Comment: Which version of the library are you using?

Comment: When I install twilio, it gives `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\smitk\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages\\twilio\\rest\\api\\v2010\\account\\sip\\domain\\auth_types\\auth_type_registrations\\auth_registrations_credential_list_mapping.py'`

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Please make sure the file path of the installed Twilio module does not exceed Windows path length limit of 260 characters.

For Windows 10 Version 1607 and later, you can also [enable long file paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later) to address the issue.